# How to validate position by position in a string using regex

Tags: regex

I am having a problem that I can not resolve yet. The problem is the following:

My application have to validate a string of 11 characters, but the question is how to execute a validation for each character without use any code different of a regular expression.

**List of validations by position**

- Position 1 – numeric values 1 thru 9
- Position 2 – alphabetic values A thru Z (minus S, L, O, I, B, Z)
- Position 3 – alpha-numeric values 0 thru 9 and A thru Z (minus S, L, O, I, B, Z)
- Position 4 – numeric values 0 thru 9
- Position 5 – alphabetic values A thru Z (minus S, L, O, I, B, Z)
- Position 6 – alpha-numeric values 0 thru 9 and A thru Z (minus S, L, O, I, B, Z)
- Position 7 – numeric values 0 thru 9
- Position 8 – alphabetic values A thru Z (minus S, L, O, I, B, Z)
- Position 9 – alphabetic values A thru Z (minus S, L, O, I, B, Z)
- Position 10 – numeric values 0 thru 9
- Position 11 – numeric values 0 thru 9

Could you help me to know how to execute that using one regular expression?

For example, I can validate the first position using ^.{0}(?:[0-9]), that using quantifiers, but I do not know how to validate in the same regular expression all the 11 positions.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use the following regex.

```
(?(DEFINE)(?<alpha>(?![SLOIBZ])[A-Z])(?<alphanumeric>(?![SLOIBZ])[0-9A-Z]))\d(?&alpha)(?&alphanumeric)[1-9](?&alpha)(?&alphanumeric)\d(?&alpha){2}\d{2}
```

or without subroutines if you use regex implementation that doesn't support them.

```
[1-9]((?![SLOIBZ])[A-Z])((?![SLOIBZ])[0-9A-Z])\d((?![SLOIBZ])[A-Z])((?![SLOIBZ])[0-9A-Z])\d((?![SLOIBZ])[A-Z]){2}\d{2}
```

Please see [this link](https://regex101.com/r/pAPPas/3) to try it against different use cases. And make sure the matchers are in the right position.

## Explanation:

`(?(DEFINE)(?<alpha>(?![SLOIBZ])[A-Z])` -- Defines a subroutine which will match any alphabetic upper case char except SLOIBZ
`(?<alphanumeric>(?![SLOIBZ])[0-9A-Z]))` -- Defines a subroutine which will match any number or upper case char except SLOIBZ
`\d` -- match any digit
`(?&alpha)` -- match against defined subroutine alpha

Comment: Hi, this regex fails. If you try: **0A00A00YA00**, which is invalid, it does not fulfill position 1 requirements. It also does not evaluate the last 2 positions

Comment: Great!, god nite, it is 2 am for me

Comment: Thank you so much guys, you are great!

Comment: Sorry, guys I am trying the expression in https://regex101.com and looks good, but when I try to use it in visual studio (.net framework 4.5.1) I have the following message: "Unrecognized grouping construct". I understand that it is probably a problem related with an specific implementation in .NET (inside the library or framework). Do you know how resolve that?

Comment: Seems like .NET doesn't support subroutines. You can rewrite the regex without them. Just replace `(?&alpha)` with `(?![SLOIBZ])[A-Z])` and `(?&<alphanumeric>)` with `(?![SLOIBZ])[0-9A-Z])` and remove all the `(?(DEFINE)...)` part.

Comment: So cool genius, I just test using VS2017 and C# and it is running. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi man, I have a question. The expression looks good but for the Position 1 – numeric values 1 thru 9, and the expression is looking for 0-9. Could you help me changing it?

Comment: changed to [1-9] (instead of \d)

Comment: I m changing the regexp: [1-9]((?![SLOIBZ])[A-Z])((?![SLOIBZ])[0-9A-Z])\d((?![SLOIBZ])[A-Z])((?![SLOIBZ])[0-9A-Z])\d((?![SLOIBZ])[A-Z]){2}\d{2}   It is Ok?

Answer (score 0):

I come out with this one, which is pretty like to Moti Korets' code

```
(?(DEFINE)(?'ch'(?![SLOIBZ])[A-Z]))[1-9](?P>ch)(\d|(?P>ch))\d(?P>ch)(\d|(?P>ch))\d(?P>ch){2}\d{2}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry,  I am trying the expression in regex101.com and looks good, but when I try to use it in visual studio (.net framework 4.5.1) I have the following message: "Unrecognized grouping construct". I understand that it is probably a problem related with an specific implementation in .NET (inside the library or framework). Do you know how resolve that?

Comment: About that, sorry, since year 2000 I do not touch, use or do anything in Windows. Add to your question the tag ".NET"